# Passing along variable inside link works only on first word in multiple-word-variables, why?

Tags: php, html, variables

I have this code below. As you can see I am passing two variables along with the link.
The second variabye (`category`) works whenever it consists of one word, but some categories are two words or more, and then on the receiving php page where I fetch the variable only the first word is fetched.

Example: I pass along this: `Rims & Tires`
Only this comes through: `Rims`

```
$display_table .= "<a href='../ad.php?ad_id=$row[ad_id]&category=$row[category]' target='_parent'>";
```

Here is how I fetch it in the receiving php file (which the link is to):

```
$cat = $_GET['category'];
echo $cat; //displays only first word of multiple word categories.
```

Comment: I'm very disturbed that none of the 4 answers so far have mentioned replacing `&` with `&amp;` *(except maybe tvanfosson, though it's not explicit)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the proper encoding. For query data use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
"<a href='../ad.php?ad_id=".urlencode($row['ad_id'])."&category=".urlencode($row['category'])."' target='_parent'>"
```

And since the `&` inside the attribute value also need to be encoded properly (using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)):

```
"<a href='".htmlspecialchars("../ad.php?ad_id=".urlencode($row['ad_id'])."&category=".urlencode($row['category']))."' target='_parent'>"
```

Producing proper code makes things a lot more difficult and when using the variant above probably also a lot more unreadable. But you can split the steps like this:

```
$row['ad_id'] = urlencode($row['ad_id']);
$row['category'] = urlencode($row['category']);
$href = htmlspecialchars("../ad.php?ad_id=$row[ad_id]&category=$row[category]");
$display_table .= "<a href='$href' target='_parent'>";
```

And if *ad_id* is always a numeric value, you don’t even need to apply `urlencode` on it.

Comment: My first suggestion using *ENT\_QUOTES* quote style replacement is not necessary as `urlencode` is already replacing the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$display_table .= "<a href='../ad.php?ad_id=".urlencode($row[ad_id])."&category=".urlencode($row[category])."' target='_parent'>";
```